# eCommerce tracking data not being sent with react-ga

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

I'm having trouble sending eCommerce tracking data to google currently I am able to see page views fine but it is not registering the events for conversions.

Here is my current setup:

```
// Application entry point
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';

import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
ReactGA.initialize('UA-myID-2');
ReactGA.plugin.require('ecommerce');

// Google Analytics
function fireTracking() {
  ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname, location.pathname);
  ReactGA.plugin.execute('ecommerce', 'addTransaction', {
    id: 'jd38je31j',
    revenue: '3.50'
  });
}

render (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} routes={routes} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), fireTracking} />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I've added the code below for testing eCommerce data but nothing is being sent what am I doing wrong here?

```
ReactGA.plugin.execute('ecommerce', 'addTransaction', {
  id: 'jd38je31j',
  revenue: '3.50'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working by dispatching the data to ga on a verified payment

```
  verifyAlipay() {
    const {dispatch} = this.props;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: `${API_URL}/orders/${this.props.location.query.out_trade_no}/complete`
    }).then(resp => {
      if (resp.result == 'success') {
        dispatch(fetchCart());
        ReactGA.plugin.execute('ecommerce', 'addTransaction', {
          'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
          'name': 'test checkout',          // Product name. Required.
          'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
          'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
          'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
          'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
        });
        ReactGA.plugin.execute('ecommerce', 'send');
        ReactGA.plugin.execute('ecommerce', 'clear');
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a module before importing it. First you need to import the plugin using ReactGA.plugin.require()

https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga#reactgapluginrequirename-options

Comment: I've added the following `ReactGA.plugin.require('ecommerce', { path: '/log', debug: true });` at the top of my file but it's still not working:( any ideas?

Comment: @nooBskie: Did you manage to get this working? I have the same issue

Comment: @cubabit added a answer